# Where to start reading into p-adic non-abelian Hodge theory?

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request

I'm curious about Faltings' ["A $p$-adic Simpson correspondence"](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2005.05.026). Do you know more detailed, introductory,  expositions, surveys, texts of seminars on that?

Edit: Annette Werner's survey ["Vector Bundles on Curves over $\mathbb{C}_p$"](https://www.uni-frankfurt.de/50581177/survey.pdf) seems to be related.

Edit: The [first part](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.5466) of a "new approach for the p-adic Simpson correspondence, closely related to the original approach of Faltings, but also inspired by the work of Ogus and Vologodsky on an analogue in characteristic p>0". [Another related article](https://hal.science/file/index/docid/337672/filename/Higgs.pdf).

Edit: today new in arXiv - ["Non-abelian Hodge theory for algebraic curves over characteristic p"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.0299)

Comment: There's now also a book on this topic by Abbes, Gros and Tsuji.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't answer the question, but you might want to check out Martin Olsson's
[Towards non--abelian $P$--adic Hodge theory in the good reduction case](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Emolsson/PHT3-24-08.pdf).

In another (maybe too different to be useful - I'm totally ignorant here)
direction there's the work of Ogus and Vologodsky
[Nonabelian Hodge Theory in Characteristic p](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0507476).

Comment: Thanks! After browsing both articles I could not see how they and Faltings' article relate to each other. 

Comment: A comment from an expert: "The relationship between the three approaches is not so clear, and in fact the aim of each of the theories is quite different. For example the Ogus-Vologodsky theory is with positive characteristic coefficients, whereas Olsson and the work of Faltings is with char 0 coefficients. Also in Olsson the idea is to work with a big category of isocrystals and look at the action of Frobenius/Galois on the whole category, whereas Faltings approach is to study the category of representations of the fundamental group over the ground field."